# Using CakePHP to query a database of coordinates to return JSON for Google Map

Tags: json, cakephp, google-maps-api-3

I have the following example: http://dev.driz.co.uk/googlemap/ that represents the mapping functionality of an app I'm building in CakePHP (note this example isn't using Cake).

Using JSON, I'm populating the Google Map with some markers and also using Geolocation to center the map on your location, essentially so you can see posts around you. So in the real life app that JSON file will be dynamically built using Cake from a database.

What I want to do is using the coordinates of your location (the user) query the database to find posts that are say within a 10 mile radius of those coordinates. And pull say 10 posts out... I then want to make it so that you can drag the map around and load in more posts as you extend your radius if that makes sense. **The problem is how to pass the coordinates/10 miles radius back to CakePHP to query the posts in the DB!**

Are there any examples of this? And could someone post some code samples that could help to get me started building such a query? I have a query in place for pulling out 10 posts from the database, but it doesn't search for posts based on coordinates... How would I do that within a set 10 mile radius for a set of coordinates?

An example of the query is:

```
public function gMapTest() {

        $posts = $this->Post->find('all', array('limit'=>10,'conditions'=>array('Post.status'=>array(1,2)),'order'=>array('Post.datetime'=>'desc'),
        'contain'=>array('User'=>'Profile'))); 

        $this->set('posts',$posts);

        $this->set('_serialize', 'posts');
    }
```

Comment: Your question has not been properly set. From the comments on one of the answers the problems seems to be sending and returning data from CakePHP database. You should be using AJAX to perform this.There are many tutorials on this. Personally I would use JQuery for this see http://idhana.com/2009/03/29/ajax-in-cakephp-with-jquery/

Comment: **I know how to use AJAX with CakePHP. I use it all over my app.** What I don't know, is how to send some coordinates to my database and return 10 posts that are within a 10 mile radius to those coordinates as it's not a simple find statement.

Comment: find wont do it you need to use query. See my answer using Haversine formula. As I only use PHP I cant confirm the Sanitize function. See http://daviestrachan.zxq.net/maps/stationmap8.php which uses this function to view railway stations in UK

Answer (score 0):

Use the Geocoder behavior on your model:

```
$this->Post->Behaviors->attach('Tools.Geocoder');
$this->Post->setDistanceAsVirtualField($lat, $lng);
$options = array('order' => array('Post.distance' => 'ASC'), 'limit' => 10);
$posts = $this->Post->find('all', $options);
```

http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/06/12/geocoding-with-cakephp/

Comment: How do I pass the coordinates from the Google Map to the controller? And then pass the response back again?

Comment: I thought you want to make a find(all) call? then you should geocode your records prior to the save call (using the behavior). this way you have the coordinates saved in those records (lat/lng fields) and can easily retrieve them via find.

Comment: All the records in the DB are geocoded with coordinates already as the posts have two columns for lat and long. The problem is being able to search these records to find places near the location of the user.

Comment: you did read the example and the linked article, didnt you? if you want to stay on the same page you can use ajax to submit the coordinates to the controller action where you retrieve the records.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean when you say: `then you should geocode your records prior to the save call (using the behavior)`. As the records are geocoded already as I save the coordinates using a google map to get the users location and geolocation coords... See example here of how I do that: http://dev.driz.co.uk/location/ - My problem is pulling the results back out based on user location and drag of the map. Could you show an example? Very confused. Thanks!