# Getting nearby data from lat/lng in CakePHP

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm trying using Euromark's Geocoding behavior (part of his Tools plugin) to get nearby posts in my CakePHP 2.4.3 app, and have been coming up with an SQL error. This is my controller code:

```
    $this->Post->Behaviors->attach('Tools.Geocoder');
    $this->Post->setDistanceAsVirtualField(44, 50);  //or whatever coords
    $options = array(
        'contain' => array(), //same error when I don't use this, just using it to keep the SQL query easier to read
        'order' => array('Post.distance' => 'ASC', 'limit' => 10)
    );
    $posts = $this->Post->find('all', $options);
    $this->set('posts', $posts);
```

This throws an SQL error; It says there's a problem with the syntax:

```
SELECT 
    `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`lat`, `Post`.`lng`, `Post`.`body`, 
    (6371.04 * ACOS(
        COS(
            PI() / 2 - RADIANS(90 - `Post`.`lat`)
        ) * COS(
            PI() / 2 - RADIANS(90 - 44)
        ) * COS(
            RADIANS(`Post`.`lng`) - RADIANS(50)
        ) + SIN(
            PI() / 2 - RADIANS(90 - `Post`.`lat`)
        ) * SIN(
            PI() / 2 - RADIANS(90 - 44)
        )
    )) AS `Post__distance`
FROM `database`.`posts` AS `Post` 
WHERE 1 = 1 

ORDER BY 
    (6371.04 * ACOS(
        COS(
            PI() / 2 - RADIANS(90 - `Post`.`lat`)
        ) * COS(
            PI() / 2 - RADIANS(90 - 44)
        ) * COS(
            RADIANS(`Post`.`lng`) - RADIANS(50)
        ) + SIN(
            PI() / 2 - RADIANS(90 - `Post`.`lat`)
        ) * SIN(
            PI() / 2 - RADIANS(90 - 44)
        )
    )) ASC, 
`limit` 10
```

I'm using the latest version of the plugin, it says it's for Cake 2.x. My posts have geolocation data stored as `Post.lat` and `Post.lng`. Any ideas why it would be creating malformed SQL? My SQL skills are such I can't spot the error, presumably the plugin is OK and there's something about my controller action.

Comment: Seems like it is working nicely then now :) PS: in newer versions you can use load() instead of attach(). The latter is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end you've got a comma after ASC and limit is in backticks. Cake does strange things with SQL queries when it gets given arguments that it doesn't expect. I suspect your problem is with this:

```
'order' => array('Post.distance' => 'ASC', 'limit' => 10)
```

Try:

```
'order' => 'Post.distance ASC',
'limit' => 10
```

Comment: The array version for order works just fine - if closing brackets are where they belong.. ;) See my answer.

Comment: Hi mark. The array is unnecessary since there is only one order criteria passed, which is why I've removed it. It doesn't make any difference other than lengthening the code if it's there.

Comment: I always use the verbose array way ;) But that's just preference. I just wanted to point out that the original issue is the wrong bracket placement, not array vs string.

Answer (score 0):

You basically nest your arrays wrongly

```
'order' => array('Post.distance' => 'ASC', 'limit' => 10)
```

should be (note the closing brackets)

```
'order' => array('Post.distance' => 'ASC'), 'limit' => 10
```

Comment: Yeah, I was basing my code directly off what you suggested over here. My bad, I could have been banging my head off that one all night! http://stackoverflow.com/a/12421186/3088826